# How to set an arbitrary limit on a foreach loop?

Tags: asp.net

I've got a `foreach` loop fetches everything, but I want it to stop after 10. It appears that I should use `for` instead. But I don't understand how to write that while still assigning the required var.

```
    @foreach (var p in posts)
{ 
        <item>
                <title>@p.GetProperty("zContentTitle").Value</title>
                <dc:creator>@p.GetProperty("zPostAuthor").Value</dc:creator>
                <category>@p.GetProperty("zPostCategories")</category>
                <description>@p.GetProperty("zContentBody").Value.StripHtml().Trim()</description>
                <link>http://@Request.Url.Host@landing.Url@p.Url</link>
                <guid isPermaLink="false">http://@Request.Url.Host@landing.Url@p.Url</guid>
                <pubDate>@p.GetProperty("zPostDate").Value.FormatDateTime("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss") CST</pubDate>
        </item>
}
```

Comment: for and foreach in this scenario will accomplish the same task. Try setting a break point and see how many elements are in "posts" it should equal to how many iterations your seeing.

Comment: forgive me if this doesn't address your answer my first time in working with asp. When this runs now it returns all 66 posts (currently and growing). I want it to stop at 10.

Comment: Ah. Use jessegavin's solution or use a for() loop and you can hard code the value 10. Not sure about the view syntax but would be similar to for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {}

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I limit the number of elements iterated over in a foreach loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014364/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-elements-iterated-over-in-a-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that small amount of code it's hard to tell, which of the many options you should use. It seems that the "posts" in

```
@foreach (var p in posts)
{
  ...
}
```

is of type IEnumerable. So you could use the extension method Take(). Your code would look like this:

```
@foreach (var p in posts.Take(10))
{ 
    <item>
            <title>@p.GetProperty("zContentTitle").Value</title>
            <dc:creator>@p.GetProperty("zPostAuthor").Value</dc:creator>
            <category>@p.GetProperty("zPostCategories")</category>
            <description>@p.GetProperty("zContentBody").Value.StripHtml().Trim()</description>
            <link>http://@Request.Url.Host@landing.Url@p.Url</link>
            <guid isPermaLink="false">http://@Request.Url.Host@landing.Url@p.Url</guid>
            <pubDate>@p.GetProperty("zPostDate").Value.FormatDateTime("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss") CST</pubDate>
    </item>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `posts` implements the [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) interface and if you're using `System.Linq` you could do this.

```
@foreach (var p in posts.Take(10))
```

Otherwise you could do something like....

```
@{ var counter = 0; }

@foreach(var p in posts) {

  counter++;
  if (counter == 10)
    break;

        <item>
                <title>@p.GetProperty("zContentTitle").Value</title>
                <dc:creator>@p.GetProperty("zPostAuthor").Value</dc:creator>
                <category>@p.GetProperty("zPostCategories")</category>
                <description>@p.GetProperty("zContentBody").Value.StripHtml().Trim()</description>
                <link>http://@Request.Url.Host@landing.Url@p.Url</link>
                <guid isPermaLink="false">http://@Request.Url.Host@landing.Url@p.Url</guid>
                <pubDate>@p.GetProperty("zPostDate").Value.FormatDateTime("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss") CST</pubDate>
        </item>
}
```